# How can I access missing hard drive partitions?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8

I recently installed Ubuntu 13.04 alongside Windows 8. I had 4 drives and now I can access only 2 drives.

How can I access the other 2 drives from Windows 8?

Answer (score 0):

Well, in what you formated your Linux disks?

Default for Windows is only able to handle FAT and NTFS...do you mean the fact, that it may show the partition in Windows 8 partition manager? That is because it can see it, but not recognize the "ext" partition(s).

I found a "open source" software that can do it...not sure about Win 8, as it says only Windows 7 is supported, but it's worth a shot.

["ext2fsd" program link](http://www.ext2fsd.com/)

Comment: yes it shows the partition in "Disk Management" and in "ext2fsd"
but i want to access those drives how should i access them